# String identitical to id of an element returns the element

Tags: javascript, html

I've encountered a situation which works but I dont understand why. If I name an element `id="abc"` and do `console.log(abc)` without setting it first, it gives me the HTML Object. Could anyone explain this behaviour?

Example

```
<h1 Id="abc" >abcdefghj</h1> 

<script>
  // without using document.getElementById
  console.log(abc); // Returns h1 element  
 </script>
```

I don't know why it's give me the whole element without using document.getElementById().

Comment: `id` attribute is defined at global scope. this is why overuse of id's  is not considered as best practice

Comment: I think following question can be usefull [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: `abc` is **not** a string. `"abc"` is. `abc` is an identifier, and will be first looked up in local scope, then in global, and then in the window object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a legacy feature of the DOM API: basically, anything with an ID is accessible by its key in the window object, i.e. `window[id]`.

In your case, `abc` is essentially `window.abc`, which is a reference to the element with the ID of `abc` (i.e. matching the `#abc` selector).

This is also a reason why IDs in a HTML document must be unique, and that browser behavior of handling duplicated ID is technically undefined by spec.

---

On a related note, because of this feature, it is dangerous to give your elements IDs that may override native functions/prototypes. Here is an example: `<button id="submit">` when located in a form. When you try to programmatically submit the form using `formElement.submit()`, you actually run into an error, because now the `formElement.submit` actually refers to the nested button element with the ID of `submit` instead of the native method. You can try this out yourself here:

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

const helloButton = document.getElementById('btn');
helloButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myForm.submit();
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" />
  <button id="submit">
    Submit form
  </button>
  <button id="btn" type="button">
    Click me to programmatically submit form
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this legacy feature, we learn every day !

Comment: Note: IIRC this used to be unreliable but in HTML5 it is now standard.

Comment: You might want to include another tidbit in your answer: `abc` is not, as claimed by the OP, a string (that would be `"abc"`), but it is an identifier, and as such it is treated as a name and name lookup happens.

Comment: @user253751 Being standardised for legacy compatibility reasons doesn't prevent it from being deprecated.